# simple makefile libs variable - replacing implicit rules

Tags: c, makefile

Say I want a very simple makefile that includes libraries to link (lets say `-lm`)

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
LIBS=-lm
```

How do I get `$(LIBS)` to the right part of the command without having to manually construct the command inside the makefile and breaking a bunch of the implicit rules?

[I couldn't find anything in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables)

Is it possible to simply replace the implicit rule with one written myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables) you gave, there's the `LDFLAGS` :

```
LDFLAGS
Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’.
```

Comment: The `-lm` flag has to be after the source file, the `LDFLAGS` variable is placed before it.

Comment: Then you'll have to use the `LOADLIBES` var

Comment: I had the same problem once ... but if I remember it only works for simple linking ...